# Zend changing validation error behavior: wrapping element in another tag

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-validate

I've set a validator for the email so it can't be empty.

This is the markup of the usual form that zend_form generates:

```
<dt id="email-label"><label class="required" for="email">Email</label></dt>
<dd id="email-element">
   <input type="text" value="" id="email" name="email">
</dd>
```

When validation fails, zend_form adds a new `ul class="errors"` inside the dd

```
<dt id="email-label"><label class="required" for="email">Email</label></dt>
<dd id="email-element">
   <input type="text" value="" id="email" name="email">
   <ul class="errors">
      <li>Value is required and can't be empty</li>
   </ul>
</dd>
```

How can I change this default behavior slightly so that the entire `dt dd` gets wrapped in a single `p` or `something` that I can add an error class to? My guess is that I need to specify to zend_form how to behave when an element has errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own decorator to do that, something simple like this::

```
class My_Decorator_ElementWrapper extends Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract
{
    public function render($content)
    {
        $class = 'form-element';
        $errors = $this->getElement()->getMessages();
        if (!empty($errors))
            $errors .= ' has-errors';
        return '<div class="'.$class.'">' . $content . '</div>';
    }
}
```

Now you can just register this decorator for the element:

```
$element->addPrefixPath('My_Decorator', 'My/Decorator/', 'decorator');
$element->addDecorator('ElementWrapper');
```

You can also register the prefix path for all elements at the same time by using `$form->addElementPrefixPath()` instead.

If you want to add this decorator (and the prefix path) automatically for all elements, I suggest you extend each element the Zend's corresponding one (eg. make `My_Form_Element_Text` that extends `Zend_Form_Element_Text`), and then add the prefix path in the init function, and override `loadDefaultDecorators()` method to add the `ElementWrapper` at the end of the decorator chain. For example, this is how `loadDefaultDecorators()` looks for `Zend_Form_Element_Text`:

```
public function loadDefaultDecorators()
{
    if ($this->loadDefaultDecoratorsIsDisabled()) {
        return $this;
    }

    $decorators = $this->getDecorators();
    if (empty($decorators)) {
        $this->addDecorator('ViewHelper')
            ->addDecorator('Errors')
            ->addDecorator('Description', array('tag' => 'p', 'class' => 'description'))
            ->addDecorator('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dd',
                                            'id'  => $this->getName() . '-element'))
            ->addDecorator('Label', array('tag' => 'dt'));
    }
    return $this;
}
```

You'd just add a `->addDecorator('ElementWrapper')` at the end of the chain. So to show a concrete example of `My_Form_Element_Text`:

```
class My_Form_Element_Text extends Zend_Form_Element_Text
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->addPrefixPath('My_Decorator', 'My/Decorator/', 'decorator');
    }

    public function loadDefaultDecorators()
    {
        if ($this->loadDefaultDecoratorsIsDisabled()) {
            return $this;
        }

        $decorators = $this->getDecorators();
        if (empty($decorators)) {
            $this->addDecorator('ViewHelper')
                ->addDecorator('Errors')
                ->addDecorator('Description', array('tag' => 'p', 'class' => 'description'))
                ->addDecorator('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dd',
                                                'id'  => $this->getName() . '-element'))
                ->addDecorator('Label', array('tag' => 'dt'))
                ->addDecorator('ElementWrapper');
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```